# Writing an android app to take screenshot

Tags: android, screenshot

I want to make an app for Android that allows the user to take screenshot. I want to use the permission READ_FRAME_BUFFER for writing this app.

Can someone please guide to a useful resource?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/screenshot-android

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Android Screenshot Library for the same purpose.

Please visit this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/).